# Windows 7, device drivers missing after reboot

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I've encountered an odd and unusual (at least for me) problem:

I've installed a card printer, which has a built in third party r-fid encoder in it.

On the first setup of the printer and encoder, with a different driver for each device, each provided by the manufacturer, everything works fine, the printer prints and the encoder encodes as expected. The problem is that when I reboot the machine, for some reason, the encoder drivers are missing. The printer works fine, but windows does not detect the encoder plugged in nor it has the drivers installed.

My question is: what steps can I take to find out what the problem is?

What I've tried so far:

- Unplugging and plugging back on the printer and switching usb ports
- Manually installing both drivers
- Letting the system download the encoders drivers automatically from windows update
- Checked the driver installation folder and folder access

The device (both printer and encoder) works fine on windows 10 machines, and the manufacturer says they work fine on windows 7 machines too, so far I seem to be the only one with this problem

The computers I've tried installing it on run a windows 7 SP1